# Rails 5: How to DRY Multiple Conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have many user types which all show different things in the view:

```
- if current_user.type == 'newbie' || current_user.type == 'super_admin'
  | Button A
- if current_user.type == 'regular' || current_user.type == 'experienced' || current_user.type == 'admin' || current_user.type == 'super_admin'
  | Button B
- if current_user.type == 'experienced' || current_user.type == 'manager' || current_user.type == 'admin' || current_user.type == 'super_admin'
  | Button C
...
```

I tried to shorten it by defining the common conditions:

#### application_controller.rb

```
def user_is_admin
  current_user.type == 'admin' || current_user.type == 'super_admin'
end
```

#### view

```
- if current_user.type == 'regular' || current_user.type == 'experienced' || user_is_admin
  | Button B
```

But I get an error:

```
Did you mean?  user_signed_in?
```

Comment: You can access the `application_controller` methods from Controller classes as they inherit from `application controller`. Thus you cannot call it in your ERB or through a model.

Comment: Depends what "Button A" and friends really do. Ideally you could push that logic elsewhere and just say `if current_user.can_do_button_a_things?`, `if current_user.can_do_button_b_things?`, ... but hard to say without knowing more.

Comment: Did one of the answers work for you?

Comment: Yes, it worked. I made a helper def current_user_is_newbie? ['newbie', 'super_admin'].include?(current_user.kind) and used that in the views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick fix, how about something like:

```
- if ['newbie', 'super_admin'].include?(current_user.type)
  | Button A
- if ['regular', 'experienced', 'admin'].include?(current_user.type)
  | Button B
- if ['experienced', 'manager', 'admin'].include?(current_user.type)
  | Button C
```

To follow up on the answer from Shiko, I would not personally put this logic in the model as I limit my models strictly to data access (and this is business logic). But, that is a matter of personal preference.

Instead, I would be tempted to put this in a `decorator`. But that's a longer discussion.

Comment: Thanks! I made a helper ['newbie', 'super_admin'].include?(current_user.kind) and used that in the views

Answer (score 0):

As @jvillian mentioned `.include?`, there also regex option

`<%= button B if current_user.type =~ /^(regular|experienced|admin)$/ %>`

Comment: That's *way* too smart for me! ;-)

Comment: @jvillian its just suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

To implement the code in your questions correctly, you need **to add the code to the model** and not the controller, as below:

```
class User
  def is_admin
    # by the way, type is a reserver word in AR
    type == 'admin' ||  type == 'super_admin'
  end
end
```

**NB:**
You can access the *application_controller* methods from **Controller** classes as they *inherit* from application controller.